# What does Firebase's FacebookAuthProvider.addScope do?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

What does Firebase's FacebookAuthProvider.addScope do? Is it needed to retrieve an access token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used to add Facebook OAuth 2.0 scopes such as: 'public_profile', 'email', 'user_likes', 'user_friends', etc.
For example:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_friends');
provider.addScope('user_likes');
// This will open the Facebook sign in page and ask user to consent
// to the additional scopes.
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  if (result.user) {
   // Additional user info like Facebook account url, gender, etc.
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.profile);
    // Facebook access token returned in the process
    // for the scopes requested.
    console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
  }
});
```

Comment: So, how this accessToken has to be used?

Comment: Check the Facebook documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

if some one came a cross this issue:
`provider.addScope('scope')` example `scope = email` requests user permission to his email. and The authentication provider "google for example" tell user for that so the user could deny or grant this permission. if granted the user will be sign in and the developer can retrieve this scope.